# React-Select True False From Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-select

I'm cracking my head trying to solve this. I have a `bootstrap` table that returns some value from an API call. I'd like to render a true/false dropdown button in the table based on a returned JSON from a map. I need the button to default to whatever value `{selection.tradableOverride}` is (it's only ever `true/false`).

I've chosen `React-Select` for this but am open to other solutions.

```
<td>
  <Select
      defaultValue={selection.tradableOverride}
      options={[
          { value: 'true', label: 'true' },
          { value: 'false', label: 'false' }
      ]}
  ></Select>
</td>
```

Here's the output at the moment:

[image]

Comment: Instead of defaultValue try value prop

Comment: Are the value properties of each option object supposed to be strings, if your selection.tradableOverride value is only ever a boolean? Trying to understand if that’s not just a typo.

Comment: Hi @StephenCollins, `{selection.tradableOverride}` should return a boolean...

Comment: your options value are in string and in defaultValue it should be a string then only it will match